# Refresh issue on iphone

Tags: bug, mobile-web

Occasionally, on my iPhone, pushing the button "questions" brings up the newest 50 questions only (when set to that number), with no option to go to older pages (page 2, 3, ..., next, last) in or near the bottom row. This could be a client side issue with caching as it happens only occasionally; but I wondered if server-side an explicit request to invalidate the cache might remedy this? I didn't notice this before the recent interface upgrade; so checking if some small change made then maybe should be undone is another suggestion. It only happens for the meta site, not main; and I'm on the most recent iphone ios. Edit: example from another network site (using mobile version of site; but not app):

[image]

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier.: so this is a network-wide issue, at least for me under the parameters given above. The above was after hitting "questions" 3 times, and checking after each time if the "next" section now showed.

Comment: Ok, now it's clear this is not MathJax. I tagged this mobile-web, following the [Meta format](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-web?sort=newest&pageSize=15) for this topic. As Dave Haney explained [elsewhere](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15172/not-allowed-to-suggest-edits-via-se-app/15173#comment57626_15173), they can monitor such tags network-wide. (Also, this is a pure bug report, not a feature request.)

Comment: @Thisis: Thank you. It's not the biggest issue, but a proud developer might want to track this apparent bug down. :)

Comment: One more little thing (for the future): today's high-density mobile displays make for oversized screenshots. You may have noticed that I reduced the size of the screenshot in your post: all it took was to add the letter `l` at the end of the  filename, before the extension. There is also `m` parameter for "medium", others are much too small.